# Java - Object Mapper - JSON Array of Number to List<Long>

Tags: java, arrays, json, list

In my front end I send this JSON:

```
"ids": [ 123421, 15643, 51243],
"user": {
   "name": "John",
   "email": "john@sovfw.com.br" 
}
```

To my Spring Endpoint below:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/sendToOficial")
public ResponseEntity<?> sendToOficial(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) {

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Long> pointsIds = mapper.convertValue( payload.get("pointsIds"), List.class );
UsuarioDTO autorAlteracao = mapper.convertValue(payload.get("user"), UsuarioDTO.class);

for (Long idPoint : pointsIds) { ... }
```

But I'm getting a Cast Exception in the for saying that it can't cast Integer to Long.

I can't receive the "ids" numbers as Integer, I want to receive as Long.
Please, how could I do this?

Comment: Just for the record: and you need "Long" (instead of Integer) ... because your IDs will fit in Longs, but not Integer values?

Comment: The IDs in the example fits in the Integer. But in The database I have NUMBER(18) that, if I'm not wrong, needs to be Long

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, define POJOs for mapping your request object:

```
public class RequestObj implements Serializable{

    private List<Long> ids;

    private UsuarioDTO user;

    /* getters and setters here */

}

public class UsuarioDTO implements Serializable{

    private String name;
    private String email;

    /* getters and setters here */

}
```

And then modify your endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/sendToOficial")
public ResponseEntity<?> sendToOficial(@RequestBody RequestObj payload) {
```

In this way you also do not need to use an `ObjectMapper`. Just call `payload.getIds()`.

Consider also that in this way if payload changes you'll need only to change `RequestObj` definition, while using `ObjectMapper` would force you to update also your endpoint in an important way. It's better and safer to separate payload representation from control logic.

Comment: Sounds like a sane approach.

Comment: I think that this is the best ideia. Worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 6):

If you just want your mapper to read into a `List<Long>`, [use this trick](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) for obtaining full generics type information by sub-classing.

**Example**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Long>listOfLong=mapper.readValue("[ 123421, 15643, 51243]" ,
                    new TypeReference<List<Long>>() {
                    });
System.out.println(listOfLong);
```

Prints

```
[123421, 15643, 51243]
```

Answer (score 4):

In *jackson-databind-2.6.x* and onward versions you can configure the `ObjectMapper` to serialize low typed `int` values (values that fit in 32 bits) as `long` values using the `DeserializationFeature#USE_LONG_FOR_INTS` configuration feature:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/sendToOficial")
public ResponseEntity<?> sendToOficial(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature .USE_LONG_FOR_INTS, true);
    List<Long> pointsIds = mapper.convertValue( payload.get("pointsIds"), List.class );
    UsuarioDTO autorAlteracao = mapper.convertValue(payload.get("user"), UsuarioDTO.class);

    for (Long idPoint : pointsIds) { // ... }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but still not working for me. Using debug I get this situation: https://imgur.com/a/ZVISRVe